# MonoTouch, NSLog, and TestFlightSdk

Tags: xamarin.ios, nslog, testflight

I am trying to integrate the [TestFlightSdk](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/) into an app I've made using [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch).

I am trying to implement logging in my app in such a way that it is picked up by the TestFlightSdk. It supposedly picks up `NSLog`ged text automatically, but I can't seem to find the right combination of code to add to my own app, written in C#/MonoTouch, that does the same.

What I've tried:

1. `Console.WriteLine("...");`
2. `Debug.WriteLine("...");` (but I think this just calls `Console.WriteLine`)
3. Implementing support for `NSlog`, but this crashed my app so apparently I did something wrong (I'll ask a new question if this is the way to go forward.)

Is there anything built into MonoTouch that will write log messages through NSLog, so that I can use it with TestFlightSdk? Or do I have to roll my own wrapper for NSLog?

In order to implement NSLog myself, I added this:

```
public static class Logger
{
    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation")]
    private extern static void NSLog(string format, string arg1);

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        NSLog("%s", message);
    }
}
```

(I got pieces of the code above from this other SO question: [How to I bind to the iOS Foundations function NSLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492586/how-to-i-bind-to-the-ios-foundations-function-nslog).)

But this crashes my app with a SIGSEGV fault.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Foundation;

public class Logger
{
    [DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.FoundationLibrary)]
    private extern static void NSLog(IntPtr message);

    public static void Log(string msg, params object[] args)
    {
        using (var nss = new NSString (string.Format (msg, args))) {
            NSLog(nss.Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll post an answer with what I ended up with!

Comment: nowadays, it is written so: [DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.FoundationLibrary)]

Answer (score 2):

Anuj pointed the way, and this is what I ended up with:

```
[DllImport(MonoTouch.Constants.FoundationLibrary)]
private extern static void NSLog(IntPtr format, IntPtr arg1);
```

and calling it:

```
using (var format = new NSString("%@"))
using (var arg1 = new NSString(message))
    NSLog(format.Handle, arg1.Handle);
```

When I tried just the single parameter, if I had percentage characters in the string, it was interpreted as an attempt to format the string, but since there was no arguments, it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine()` works as expected (it redirects to `NSLog`) on current xamarin.ios versions. Even on release builds (used by hockeyapp, etc). No need to use `DllImport` anymore.